# I am facing some issues in importing CSS modules and using it in classname

Tags: reactjs, typescript, postcss, css-modules

//here is the import of css module

`import * as styles from './global-offices.module.css';`

and when I am using it inside my div for example **className={styles.iAmClass}**
so it is giving me warning that **iAmClass** is not exported from **'./global-offices.module.css'**
***here is the css file:***

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: var(--mobile-component-buffer);

    @media (min-width: 834px) {
        margin: var(--desktop-component-buffer);
        padding: 20px 20px;

        &#galleryWrapper {
            padding: 20px 40px;
        }
    }
    .gallery {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;

        .officeCard {
            min-width: 235px;
            width: 280px;
            height: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 10px;
            overflow: visible;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: top;
            background: var(--color-gray);
            padding: 0 0 1rem;

            &:first-of-type {
                margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
            }

            @media (min-width: 414px) {
                width: 280px;
                min-height: 515px;

                &:first-of-type {
                    margin: 0 10px;
                }
            }
        }
        h5 {
            margin: 1rem 0;
        }
        p {
            margin: 0.5rem 0;

            &.siteUrl {
                color: var(--color-orange);
            }
        }
    }
    .prevArrowButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        left: -12px;

        @media (min-width: 834px) {
            left: 2px;
        }

        @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
            width: 90px;
        }
    }
    .nextArrowButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        right: -12px;

        @media (min-width: 834px) {
            right: 2px;
        }

        @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
            width: 90px;
        }
    }
    svg {
        height: 2.5rem;
    }
    .dots {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 15px;
        span {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-size: 0;
            padding: 6px;
            margin: 0 2px;
        }
    }
}

.countrySelector {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    select {
        appearance: menulist;
        margin-top: -1px;
        border: 2px solid var(--color-gray);
    }

    @media (min-width: 834px) {
        width: 650px;
    }
}

.mapContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;

    @media screen and (min-width: 834px) {
        max-width: 90%;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

.mapFrame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I am attaching screenshot of one of uses for reference

[image]

**These are the warnings I am getting when I am running it locally**
[image]

***I am also attaching typescript code for css module exports that I am using:***

```
declare module '*.css' {
    const content: { [className: string]: string };
    export default content;
}
```

Comment: Can you add relevant css file?.

Comment: @dhaker I have added relevent css file

Comment: Nesting of classes is not allowed in css, that's why it is not working for you. Move all css classes to 1st level.

Comment: @dhaker this nested css structure was working fine earlier it's just i think the problem is in the way of typescript exporting i guess

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in my CRA, however I was using CSS modules (not scss/sass), also my application was using default CSS loader from CRA (which comes out of the box). Problem was solved by:

1. Creating file `Globals.d.ts` in `./src`.
2. Adding these lines in created file
   `declare module '*.module.css' { const Styles: { [className: string]: string }; export default Styles; }`
3. Adding `/**/*.d.ts` inside `eslintignore` since eslint was treating created file as js one.
4. Installing `npm install typescript-plugin-css-modules --save-dev`
5. Creating a directory named .vscode at the root of the project (if it doesn’t already exist), and adding a new file called settings.json with the following lines: `{ "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib", "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true }`

After listed above I could import my styles within `tsx` files like this `import Styles from './index.module.css';`

I hope this helps